# Computing induced metric of semi Riemannian manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, semi-riemannian-geometry

We have the ambient space $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ with the metric $ds^2 = -dx_0^2+dx_1^2+...+dx_n^2$ and the submanifold $M = \{ x\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1} | -x_0^2+x_1^2+...+x_n^2=1\}$.

I would like to compute the Christoffel Symbold of $M$ with the induced metric. For this I'd like to compute the induced metric $h$, i.e. have the matrix $(h_{ij})$. I could reparametrize the above to $-t^2+x_1^2+...+x_n^2=1$ yielding $t^2=x_1^2+...+x_n^2-1$ or $t=\varepsilon(x_1^2+...+x_n^2-1)^{1/2} =:f(x)$ with $\varepsilon = \pm1$.

My idea was to compute $dt^2$ but I am a little confused. I know $\partial t/\partial x_k = 2\varepsilon x_k / f(x)$. I am not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Do you know that this is isometric to the hyperbolic n-space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The induced metric is given by
$$
h_{ab}=\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial y^a}\frac{\partial x^\nu}{\partial y^b}g_{\mu\nu},
$$
where $x^\mu$ is the coordinates on the ambient space with metric $g_{mu\nu}$ and $y^a$ are coordinates on the submanifold with metric $h_{ab}$.

We choose coordinates such that $g_{\mu\nu}=\eta_{\mu\nu}=$diag$(-1,1\dots,1)$, and $y^a=x^a$ for $a=1,\dots,n$, we then have that $x^0=\sqrt{x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2-1}$ and
$$
\frac{\partial x^\mu}{\partial y^a}=\begin{cases}\frac{x_a}{\sqrt{x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2-1}}\text{ if }\mu=0\\
\delta^{\mu}_a\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}
$$
We now plug in our formula to get
\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
h_{ab}dy^ady^b&=-\sum_{a,b=1}^ndy^ady^b\frac{y_ay_b}{y_1^2+\dots+y_n^2-1}+\sum_{a=1}^ndy^ady^a\left(1+\frac{y^ay^a}{y_1^2+\dots+y_n^2-1}\right)\\
&=\sum_{a=1}^ndy^ady^a-2\sum_{a>b}dy^ady^b\frac{y_ay_b}{y_1^2+\dots+y_n^2-1}.
\end{aligned}\end{equation}

Comment: A question: shouldn't the off-diagonal elements $h_{ab}$ be of the form $-y^ay^b/(y_1^2+...+y_n^2-1)$?

Comment: Yes, you're completely right, sorry I rushed it. Will edit appropriately